# Alternative to PHP deprecated function session_is_registered() for logout.php file

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a simple member login site, and I was following along with a tutorial online. However, a deprecated function is used. Here is the code.

```
<?php
session_start();

session_destroy();

if(isset($_COOKIE['id']))
{
    //remove cookie
    setcookie("$id_cookie", '', time() - 50000);
    setcookie("$pass_cookie", '', time() - 50000);
}

if(!session_is_registered('username'))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else
{
    exit('Sorry we could not log you out');
}

?>
```

I also tried `!isset($_SESSION['username'])`, but every time I try to log out, I just receive the 'Sorry we could not log you out' text.

Here is the part of my login.php file code where I set the sessions:

```
//member does exist, start sessions
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $username = $row['username'];
    $id = $row['id'];
}

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['id'] = $id;
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use

```
session_is_registered
```

use

```
if (isset($_SESSION['SESSION_VARIABLE_NAME']))
```

Comment: I also tried !isset($_SESSION['username']), but every time I try to logout I just receive the text 'Sorry we could not log you out'

Comment: give if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))

Comment: Still goes to the else statement. For some reason it is still seeing that session as set.

Comment: Just try to print_r($_SESSION) before the if statement and give exit see what values you have in session

Answer (score 1):

You may add "session_unset();" before "session_destroy();"

session_destroy() delete the session file and release the session id, but keep the $_SESSION variable in memory.

Answer (score 0):

use this with `isset`

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<pre>";
   print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";


if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Check where the the SESSSION is stored or not.

Comment: I also tried !isset($_SESSION['username']), but every time I try to logout I just receive the text 'Sorry we could not log you out'

Comment: Just try to print out the session value there using the statement print_r($_SESSION) and check where the session stored or not. I will update the code now, check this and inform me the output.

Comment: I have updated the answer , check this and inform me the output. Can u see any value printed ?

Comment: No because I seem to have broken it. I didn't know what to do since I was stuck as logged in and could not get back to the index page. I deleted the users out of the database and ran session_destroy and restarted the server, but now I'm getting an error from the browser saying "This page is not redirecting properly" when trying to get back to index

Comment: Well it is printing something now, "Array ()", as well as "Sorry we could not log you out"

Comment: That means , your sessions are cleared and your are redirecting to the index page. Check your index page codes, is there any redirect from indexpage to logout page ?

Comment: It does not look that way. Thank you for the help, I'm going to keep working on it until I get it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your log out script

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
    unset($_SESSION['username']);
    unset($_SESSION['id']);
}

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
else
{
    exit('Sorry we could not log you out');
}

?>
```